# Using SFTP on AS400 Non Linux Based OS

Tags: sftp, ibm, ibm-midrange

I am trying to establish an SFTP connection on an AS400, which is on an OS that is not running a Linux based kernel.

Any idea where I can start with this?

Comment: AS/400s typically run OS/400

Answer (score 9):

It is not installed by default but is available with the [IBM Portable Utilities for i](http://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/pw_com_porting_tools_openssh).

Here's a Midrange Wiki article about [Setting up an iSeries SSHD server](http://wiki.midrange.com/index.php/SSH#Setting_up_an_iSeries_SSHD_server) to get you started.

Comment: There is also a third-party vendor providing free SFTP (and other) software: http://www.arpeggiosoftware.com/ (Note that I have not used it, so I can't say if it's better than other alternatives.)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can connect to a machine running Windows or Linux (whatever you're comfortable working with) that has a "mapped drive" to a directory in the IFS (Integrated File System) on the AS/400. Then you just SFTP your files to the shared directory on the Linux (or Windows) machine. That way you're handling the secure FTP process with an OS you're more familiar with but the data is still ending up on the AS/400 where it needs to be.

You may also want to talk to the administrator for the AS/400, it's possible it's running Linux in an LPAR (Logical Partition) right there on the AS/400 itself.

Comment: Please note - I think JamesA's solution is the best way to go, I'm only offering an alternative suggestion because I know there are times when you need to get something accomplished NOW and that's easier to accomplish if you work with technologies you're familiar with.